# How to get timestamp in another timezone ? ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, timezone-offset

I need to get time stamp in Australia/Adelaide, so i calculate the difference between localtime and Australia timezone then i've added the offset to the current localtime. but this doesn't work.

here is my code:

```
  let timeZoneOffset = NSTimeZone(name: "Australia/Adelaide")!.secondsFromGMT - NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone().secondsFromGMT
  let austrliaTime = round(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) + NSTimeInterval(timeZoneOffset)
```

what is wrong in my code ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the timestamp is timezone sensitive? They usually aren't

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes there are time zone for utc & for another timezones. right ?

Comment: no of course there are timezones. What I'm saying is that the timestamp is usually just UTC, or actually it should. Then from that you compute the date in the desired time zone

Comment: really i didn't know that !! i will google it and read more about it. thanks

Comment: Make sure you also read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially "Time Zone != Offset". `secondsFromGMT` returns the *current* seconds from GMT.  Adelaide switches between UTC+09:30 and UTC+10:30 depending on whether DST is in effect or not.

Comment: What result exactly do you expect for a given date? What result do you get?